# Laravel - Passing users id to modal using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, modal-dialog

How do I pass users ID to the modal? Now it's just writing the id, but how do i pass it to the modal? How do I make it that it converts to users id in modal? Currently it's passing admins id. I got stuck, I know it has to do something with javascript/jquery but unfortunately I don't know what and how to do it. Please help. Thank you.

view

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h2>{{ $modal }}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="rem-mod btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Zatvori</button>
                {{ Form::open(['action'=> ['PagesController@destroy', Auth::user()->id],'method' => 'POST']) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Obrišite račun', ['class' => 'bck-mod btn btn-danger']) }}    
                {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') }}
                {{ Form::close() }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Pretraži korisnike</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Pretraži korisnike" />
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <h3 align="center">Broj korisnika: <span id="total_records"></span></h3>
                <table id="users" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Prezime</th>
                            <th>Ime</th>
                            <th>Telefon</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        fetch_user_data();

        function fetch_user_data(query = ''){
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{ route('live_search.action') }}",
                method:'GET',
                data:{query:query},
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
                    $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);
                }
            })
        }

        $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
            var query = $(this).val();
            fetch_user_data(query);
        });

        $('#users').on('click', '.remove-button', function(){
            var id=$(this).data('id');
            $("#deleteModal").modal("show");
            console.log(id);
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.bck-mod', function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{route('live_search.destroy')}}",
                method:"POST",
                data:{id:id},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                    $('#users').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                }
            })
    });
    });


</script>
```

controller

```
public function destroy(Request $reqeust, $id){
        return $id;
        $user = Auth::user();
        if($reqeust){
        if ($user->IsAdmin()){
            if($user->delete()){
                return view('pages.index'); 
            }
        }else{

    if ($user->delete()) {
        Auth::logout();
        $data = array(
            'title' => 'Dobrodošli,',
            'title2' => 'da biste nastavili, ulogirajte se!',

        );
        return view('pages.index')->with($data);
    }
}
    }
}

public function action(Request $request)
{

    if($request->ajax()){
        $output = '';
        $query = $request->get('query');
        if($query != ''){
            $data = DB::table('users')
                ->where('surname', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('phone', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orderBy('id')
                ->get();
        }else {
            $data = DB::table('users')
                ->orderBy('id')
                ->get();
        }
        $total_row = $data->count();
        if($total_row > 0){
            foreach($data as $row){
                $output .= '
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$row->surname.'</td>
                        <td>'.$row->name.'</td>
                        <td>'.$row->phone.'</td>
                        <td><button type="button" id="rowId" class="remove-button btn btn-danger" data-id="'.$row->id.'">
                        <div class="close">&#120;</div>
                        </button></td>
                    </tr>
                ';
            }
        }else{
            $output = '
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="5">Nema podataka</td>
                </tr>
            ';
        }
        $data = array(
            'table_data'  => $output,
            'total_data'  => $total_row,
        );

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of passing user id in the url you could try adding hidden input in the form. So hidden input value will change each time when you click `.remove-button`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I would do in your case is, instead of `data-id` attribute, you can generate the `delete` url for each user.

For example:

```
data-url="' . action('PagesController@destroy', ['id' => $row->id]) . '"
```

Then in your view, remove the action for the form. And in your JS on click action do this:

```
var url = $(this).data('url');
$("#deleteModal form").attr('action', url);
$("#deleteModal").modal("show");
```

Hope that this helps.

Comment: Oh my god. I tried everything except this. It works! Thank you very much!